# How can I count the number of a value in a particular row using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Database

```
    id     decline     maintaining     losing
     1        true           false       true
     2       false           false      false
     3        true            true      false
```

I want to count the number of true values based on the id using a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If this are all the columns there are, then use this:

```
SELECT id,
       (case when decline = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when maintaining= 'true' then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when losing= 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as HowMuchTrue
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: And again, why downvote for the right answer . Lame people.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(if(maintaining = 'true', 1, 0)) from table -- and here some conditions.
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, in case of `boolean` fields you can directly add them together:

```
SELECT id, decline + maintaining + losing
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98a4bd/1)

Comment: @downvoter I really don't understand the reason for downvoting a correct answer. Care to express the arguments you based your vote on?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be a little fuzzy, but I think I know what you are going for. For each row, you want to count the number of times "true" shows up in them.

To do so, we'll use a CASE statement to processes true into ones, and false into zeros

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE
    WHEN decline = 'true' THEN 1
    WHEN decline = 'false' THEN 0
    else 'check your logic'
    END as decline_processed,
    CASE
    WHEN maintaining = 'true' THEN 1
    WHEN maintaining = 'false' THEN 0
    else 'check your logic'
    END as maintaining_processed,
    CASE
    WHEN losing = 'true' THEN 1
    WHEN losing = 'false' THEN 0
    else 'check your logic'
    END as losing_processed
    FROM
    [table]
```

This gets us the following results:

```
id, decline_processed, maintaining_processed, losing_processed
1 , 1, 0, 1
2, 0, 0, 0
3, 1, 1, 0
```

From here, we can take the results and gather them and get sums for each row.

```
    SELECT
    id,
    SUM(query_result_alias.decline_processed 
+ query_result_alias.maintaining_processed 
+ query_result_alias.losing_processed
) as number_of_true_values
    FROM
    [query with case statement above] as query_result_alias
    GROUP BY
    query_result_alias.id
```

This will get these results, which I believe answers your question:

```
id, number_of_true_values
1, 2
2, 0
3, 2
```

Bonus, we can process the result into summary data

```
SELECT
COUNT(query_result_alias2.id) as counter,
query_result_alias2.number_of_true_values
FROM
[query with case statement above] as query_result_alias2
GROUP BY
query_result_alias2.number_of_true_values
```

This gets you the number of rows that have each number of true values:

```
counter, number_of_true_values
2, 2
1, 0
```

With the sample data, you will only have two results, but larger datasets would provide all of the options.